# How do we distinguish between correlated and un-correlated features/variables ? Is it relevant for a regression analysis?

Tags: regression, correlation

Correlated and un-correlated terms are frequently used in data-science and understood as if they represent correlation coefficient. Is it the right way?

Comment: Correlated seems to indicate a low level of cause and effect relation - an imperfect association or interaction. There may be a high association (generally measured or termed as correlation)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Correlation among features/attributes is indeed relevant to the regression analysis.

Correlation is the degree to which two or more features are associated with each other or exhibit some form of similarity in their distribution/progression. "*Correlated*" and "*Uncorrelated*" features are terms which we people use often but I recommend not to use it because the term "Correlated" and "Uncorrelated" are too broad to comprehend. Use "Highly Correlated", "Less Correlated" and "No Correlation".

**Correlation coefficient** is one way to express the correlation between features and it falls within the range -1 to +1. These coefficients can tell us the degree to which these features are correlated..

As we move towards +ve end we find features that are "*Positively Correlated*" which means they exhibit a high linear correlation with each other in the same direction.

At the same time if we move towards the -ve end, we find features that are "*Negatively Correlated*" which are still correlated by the way, but they exhibit a linear relationship but in opposite direction.

And in the middle, we have 0, which shows "*No Correlation*" which indicates that the features have no correlation between them and they are completely independent. Usually coefficients around 0 (but not 0)are considered as "*Less Correlated*".

Ok the terminologies are explained but why do they matter?

In Regression analysis, correlation is one of the key components since it greatly influence the decision making of regression models. Features that exert a high level of correlation (both -ve and +ve) with the target variable/feature are generally considered to be important because it directly influences the outcome.

A classic example would be "blood glucose level" in Diabetes Detection. Glucose Level and Diabetes are positively correlated i.e., people with high glucose levels in blood are prone to diabetes. So these two features naturally have a high level of correlation. At the same time, some random features like timing, name of the patient and phone number .etc exhibit "No Correlation" so they can be removed because they are not contributing to the decision making and often considered as "*Noise*".

What happens when we include features that are "Less Correlated and No Correlation"?

Features that shows "No Correlation" with the target variable are generally useless and they are obsolete in the decision making process. They can be problematic as these features might contribute to "Overfitting" which can bias the model with seemingly un-logical information.

Features that are "Less Correlated" with the target variable poses similar issues like "Overfitting" but including them sometime can be beneficial. See "Less Correlation" doesnt equate to "No Correlation" in some instance and these "Less Correlated" features can indeed be useful, despite of their reduced significance, they can be used to boost up the performance of the model. Trail and error is a good practice to see how these "Less Correlated" features affect the performance of the model

There is one more thing that I want to say,which is Multicollinearity.

Multicollinearity occurs when two or more features are "Highly Correlated" to each other beside the target variable. That means these features which influence the target variable in a similar fashion. Why is this a issue? Well, If two or more features are "Highly Correlated" with each other, then it becomes hard for the model to identify which feature is influencing the decision making process. Multicollinearity can inflate the coefficients which in turn ruins model's performance.

A common example for Multicollinearity is "Redundant features". For example, if we have a dataset which contains the following features "weight in kg" and "weight in lbs" which is redundant, can show high levels of correlation (since they are basically the same), both features will influence the model in a similar way and the coefficient calculation process will be erroneous thus decreases model's performance.

Its better to remove redundant features to remove multicollinearity or we can opt for algorithms with penalty terms such as regularization functions in algorithms like Lasso Regression, Ridge Regression or ElasticNet Regression can be used to penalize all the coefficient of features which shows multicollinearity to reduce the impact of such features.

I think this will be a complete overhaul on correlation and its significance in regression analysis. Hope you find this useful!

Answer (score 0):

The word "correlated" is an adjective and indicates "loose" association between two variables i.e. it does not indicate a (significant) causal relationship. For example, chi-squared (Pearson) test of independence for a given dataset may produce a highly significant chi-square indicating a strong association and same dataset may produce a low level of Pearson R-square(representing cause and effect relatioship) which may be insignificant. It is clear that we should avoid the misunderstanding that correlation coefficient is an equivalent for "correlated" term. The two terms do differ. For example, a high correlation/association may arise for the reason that "third factors/variables" are operating on two-variables under reference for computing "correlation coefficient".Part of high correlation may be spurious.And further,alternatively, a part of correlation may be suppressed on account of third factors and we obtain a less correlation coefficient.